# why doesn't my map command work in vi/ex?

Tags: remapping, vi, keys

I'm just learning how to use the vi editor, and was trying to make use of the following map command in my .exrc file:

```
map K 0I^I^[j0O^I^[j0
```

That is what appeared when I created the map in ex mode and typing it in manually gave me those escape codes.  I wanted it to:

1. go to the start of the line
2. Insert-mode
3. press Tab (`^I`)
4. Esc
5. go down one line
6. go to the start of the line (unnecessary I guess)
7. open a new line below
8. Tab again
9. Esc
10. go down one line and
11. go to the start of that line

But it doesn't work!  It does the 0 and the I, but then inserts the remaining map keys as if in insert mode `^I^[j0O^I^[j0`.  Please tell me, someone, why it doesn't work?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should ask this at https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you read `man vi`?

Answer (score 0):

With help from Vivian De Smedt (and mattb, who suggested I go to vi.stackexchange.com to post my question), I have learned that if I enter the :map (with the colon, *so I'm actually in ex, not vi*), ex converts the Tabs to "^I" sequences, so I assumed it would work the same way when I key in the sequence with vi in my .exrc file (but using "map", not ":map", because the book I'm reading says you don't need the : in the .exrc file).  When keying it in there, the sequence Ctrl-v Tab prints the Tab as whitespace, not as "^I".  Apparently for it to work correctly, I need the key sequence to be generated with actual tabs for the tabs, not with "^I".  Once I did that, with the map looking like this: `"map K 0I         ^[j0O   ^[j0"`, it worked fine!  Thanks for the help!